# About to overflow slide transition count?

Tags: xcode4.3, uipopovercontroller, ios5.1

I have updated to iOS 5.1 and facing this problem. I have a Master and Detail viewcontrollers. Also I'm using a splitViewController.

The problem is when I launch the app in landscape mode, it shows this error

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UIPopoverController _incrementSlideTransitionCount:]
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'About to overflow slide transition count'
```

I am using ARC and the program runs perfectly well if launched in Portrait mode. Kindly provide me suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by the fact that somewhere in your code you are trying to show the Master ViewController. While this will be perfectly ok when launched in portrait (because the Master view controller is not initially displayed) it will cause problems for landscape because the Master ViewController is displayed, therefor "overflowing your slide transition count".

Without seeing your code I can't exactly tell you which section of code is causing this but you may want to get pass this error by doing something like

```
 if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
    [run the code that is crashing your app]
}
```

This way your code will only be called when you need it (in a portrait orientation).